# check if string are just letters (no symbols and numbers) lisp

Tags: string, lisp

i need to check if a word are just with letter 
example "hfjel" return true
"df(f0" return false

and anyone can explain me the function symbol-name
 thank you for help

Comment: I suggest splitting this question into two.  `symbol-name` is pretty much unrelated to what you seem to be calling a symbol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a handy standard function called [`alpha-char-p`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_alpha_.htm#alpha-char-p) that does what you're asking for.

```
CL-USER(1): (alpha-char-p #\a)
T
CL-USER(2): (alpha-char-p #\Γ)
T
CL-USER(3): (alpha-char-p #\α)
T
CL-USER(4): (alpha-char-p #\0)
NIL
CL-USER(5): (alpha-char-p #\.)
NIL
```

You can use it in conjunction with [`every`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_everyc.htm#every):

```
CL-USER(7): (every #'alpha-char-p "word")
T
CL-USER(8): (every #'alpha-char-p "nonword7")
NIL
CL-USER(9): (every #'alpha-char-p "non-alpha-word")
NIL
CL-USER(10): (every #'alpha-char-p "今日は")
T
```

Comment: Yes, EVERY and a suitable test function (like, say, ALPHA-CHAR-P) was my immediate thought.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I commented above on diacritics because this particular case often goes unnoticed, below is an example:

```
* (defparameter *weird-letter*
        (coerce (list (code-char #x0438)
                  (code-char #x0306)) 'string))
*WEIRD-LETTER*

* *weird-letter*
"и"

* (length *weird-letter*)
2

* (every #'alpha-char-p *weird-letter*)
NIL
```

I'm actually not sure what different Lisp implementations will do here because Unicode support is different in some of them (so far I can tell).

For the code above, the expected result must've been `T`, because, in fact, two codepoints U+0438-U+0306 constitute a single letter with diacritic. There are two ways in Unicode to spell it, one is a single character, and another one is a combination of the same letter without the diacritic and the diacritic.

So, if you wanted to be super-correct, then you would have to check if, by chance, the letter is not followed by diacritic, but (lo and behold!) only some of these are actually valid letters! Unicode is serious business...

EDIT:

In order to better illustrate my case:

```
#!/opt/ActivePerl-5.14/bin/perl

binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";

my $weird_letter = "\x{0438}\x{0306}";
print "$weird_letter\n";

if ($weird_letter =~ m/^(\pL|(\pL\pM))+$/)
     { print "it is a letter!\n"; }
else { print "it is not a letter!\n"; }
```

The above would almost fairly treat this kind of characters.